# How to access a var like WORKSPACE_LOC from jython scripting (pytemplate_xx.py)?

Tags: python, eclipse, jython, pydev

I'm trying to add my user variables to use them for templates in PyDev.
After reading this [plugins/org.python.pydev.jython/jysrc/pytemplate_defaults.py](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/master/plugins/org.python.pydev.jython/jysrc/pytemplate_defaults.py)
I created a file `pytemplate_from_ini.py`, and put there something like

```py
import template_helper
from configparser import ConfigParser

def GetIniUserEmail(context):

    ini_path = ? # This is located in workspace dir, or in project dir. How to get them from given context?

    ini = ConfigParser()
    ini.read(ini_path)
    return ini.get("user", "user_email", fallback="user_email")

template_helper.AddTemplateVariable(py_context_type, 'user_email', 'My user email from ini', GetIniUserEmail)
```

So, the question is how can I get values for `${WORKSPACE_LOC}`, `${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}`, etc in python from passed `context` variable?